# Sites the ToS applies to

Tags: support, terms-of-service

The links for Terms of Service in the footers of several Stack Exchange sites that I checked all go to the [*Public Network Terms of Service*](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/) posted on stackoverflow.com, not on stackexchange.com. Are those ToS posted on stackoverflow.com the ToS that apply to all Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Also worth noting that, while the footer links to SO, copies of the ToS do exist on [other](https://blender.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) [sites](https://superuser.com/legal/terms-of-service) [too](/legal/terms-of-service), under the same relative domain (`/legal/terms-of-service`).

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the TOS itself, it applies to the entire "public Network" which does include the other SE Q&A sites and "other applications" (e.g., Area51 and chat), which is why it's in the footer, twice even:

> The Stack Overflow Network is a set of related Internet sites and other applications for questions and answers (also referred to herein as the “Network”), owned and operated by Stack Exchange, Inc. (“Stack Overflow”, “we” or “us”), a Delaware corporation. Stack Overflow welcomes you to the Network, the largest community of developers in the world, and invites you to participate in the community by sharing knowledge with your peers and colleagues. Like all communities, we ask that you participate in a manner that respects your fellow community members. To that end, we provide you with these terms of service to advise you of the legal obligations you assume when you engage with the Stack Overflow community or otherwise access or use the public Network or any services provided on the public Network (collectively, “Services”). These terms govern the use of the public Network (the “Public Network Terms”).

It does not include truly private Q&A, such as Teams (which have their own pages listed in the index; e.g., "Stack Overflow for Teams Terms of Service"):

> These Public Network Terms do NOT govern the use of our Talent, Enterprise and other Stack Overflow products and services that are not part of the public Network.

Additionally, the [API has its own TOS](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/api-terms-of-use), which applies in addition to the public Network TOS.

Note: Most or all of the legal verbiage lives on the Stack Overflow domain.

Comment: Note that SOfT does have [use restrictions](https://policies.stackoverflow.co/teams/business-terms-of-service#h3-488562abc4260), of which "(g) use the Services in violation of any applicable laws or third party rights including, but not limited to, storing or sending infringing, libelous, obscene, threatening or otherwise unlawful or tortious material, including materials that are harmful to children or that violate any privacy rights, or storing or sending malicious code;" might be relevant here. Note that I am not a lawyer